# Mediaelement.js Wordpress Plugin -- Firefox Won't Load mp3 -- .htaccess MIMES set

Tags: firefox, wordpress, mp3, mediaelement.js

Using MediaElement.js Wordpress Plug-in 2.10.3 on Wordpress 3.51

Scenario: Trying to get cross-browser/platform compatibility for serving podcast mp3 files.  Subscribers (premium) have a list of the most recent 10 podcasts that they can either listen to (where the MediaElementJS player comes in) or download.

I'm using a getElementById onclick function to pass the source mp3 file for each Listen link.  I'm hiding the MediaelementJS player div that's loaded with a dummy (silent) mp3 file* and when the user clicks on a particular Listen link, the div (and player) is made visibile, and the source file in the player is updated to the file they want to hear. ***(I found that I couldn't get the player to sit empty on my page -- even hidden -- without an actual mp3 file sourced; hence, the dummy/silent file.)

This works perfectly in Chrome, IE9, Safari, and various mobile browsers I've checked (Dolphin, default browser, and Chrome on Android).  Haven't checked IOS yet, but expect it will work.  IE8 isn't working (yet), but I have to figure that out.

**OK -- PROBLEM --**

On Firefox, I'm getting (via Firebug) the dreaded "HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg" is not supported.  Load of media resource (filename.mp3) failed."  I'm going to guess that Opera would be the same, but I have not yet tested.

As mentioned in the title, I DO have .htaccess MIMES set correctly on my Apache server.  I have not had Apache restarted because .htaccess edits don't require a restart, and bringing the site down even temporarily is not desirable at this time for reasons I can't get into here -- suffice it to say that I'm but one of many users.

This ***will*** be a dealbreaker for me, as I need Firefox working.  Oddly, I see that the demo mp3 on the MediaElements.js homepage loads fine, but that's using full js code, and not the plug-in.

I'm using the following shortcode parameters:

[mejsaudio src='(name/path of my dummy mp3 file)' preload='auto' autoplay='true']

I've tried changing "src=" to "mp3=" in the shortcode, but my getElementById function doesn't recognize the mp3 parameter.  I have not tried innerHTML to change up the parameters.

I've read where there are undocumented "mode" switches.  I tried adding "mode=auto_plugins" to my shortcode, but nothing happens.  I don't see the mode parameter being checked in the plug-in code, anyway.

So, that's where I'm at, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this isn't just a WordPress issue. This goes beyond that.

In Firefox and Opera, the Flash fallback on Videos is broken claiming a null variable exists when trying to communicate with an internet-enabled location. This happens with the Demo provided with version 2.11.0.

As for MP3s, they just don't show up at all. The player's control bar never comes up at all. Without the control bar, you can't start the player. I haven't tested to auto start, but I don't want the media to auto start, so this won't help me.

Any ideas when this will be addressed?

Comment: This is not a solution to this question. Check [answer]

Answer (score 0):

FireFox doesn't play Mp3.  You have to load .ogg files in the same folder with the same file name as the mp3's.  Leave the mp3's for other browsers, obviously.

You can convert mp3 to ogg here...http://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-ogg